# SQL Query - Count inside GROUP BY no result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery

I want to count the patient diagnosis per municipality and consultation per municipality:

so it should be:

**diagnosis per municipality + consultation per municipality**

```
SELECT COUNT(consultations.id) + 
(SELECT COUNT(patientdiagnosis.id) 
    FROM consultations 
    LEFT JOIN patientdiagnosis 
    ON patientdiagnosis.consultation_id = consultations.id
    LEFT JOIN patients
    ON consultations.patient_id = patients.id
    LEFT JOIN rcitymun
    ON patients.municipality = rcitymun.citycode 
    /*GROUP BY PER MUNICIPALITY SHOULD BE HERE*/
) as encounters, rcitymun.cityname
FROM consultations 
LEFT JOIN patients
ON consultations.patient_id = patients.id
LEFT JOIN rcitymun
ON patients.municipality = rcitymun.citycode
GROUP BY patients.municipality;
```

**current output:**

```
encounters         municipality
10323                 BATAC
10423                 NUEVA ERA
```

the encounter data is huge because it's counting all of the diagnosis instead of per municipality

what i want is to count the diagnosis per municipality.

**desired output is something like this:**

```
encounters         municipality
105                   BATAC
70                   NUEVA ERA
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data

Comment: choose any one of `MySQL` & `SQL-Server` which are different.

Comment: Maybe i'll revise the question, even i got confused. haha


as for the sample data, i can't provide it here. i don't have direct access to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to reduce this by one subquery, but often it is best to start with independently grouped subqueries.

```
SELECT
       rcitymun.cityname
     , SUM(c.consult_count) consult_count
     , SUM(d.diag_count) diag_count
FROM patients
INNER JOIN rcitymun ON patients.municipality = rcitymun.citycode
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            consultations.patient_id
          , COUNT(*) consult_count
      FROM consultations
      GROUP BY
            consultations.patient_id 
) c ON patients.id = c.patient_id
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            consultations.patient_id
          , COUNT(*) diag_count
      FROM consultations
      INNER JOIN patientdiagnosis ON patientdiagnosis.consultation_id = consultations.id
      GROUP BY
            consultations.patient_id
) d ON patients.id = d.patient_id
GROUP BY
       rcitymun.cityname
```

Comment: woww, how did you understand my question ? thanks, sire. you're good.

what do you call by this:

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT .... ) ? I didn't know that this could work.

Comment: those are  "derived tables" which is a type of "subquery"